# All versions SQL Server Registry Key

Tags: sql-server, registry

Is there any registry value that i could check to see if there is any version of SQL Server installed?
I want to check a single value...not a value for 2005 another one for 2008 etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem. I don't think there's a 'one stop shopping' location for this.

What really complicates this is the concept of named instances - where you can have multiple versions of sql installed on the same machine.

For example:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Inst1\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Inst2\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion`

For SQL 2008, at least, you can enumerate the list of instances at
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL`

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion
```

Comment: For the OP's question, this is the correct answer. The CurrentVersion key/value does persist through all editions of SQL Server beyond SQL 2005. There is a caveat to this though, it can in some instances differ to what SELECT @@VERSION will return. It can be used to get the major release, I'm guessing it is just some hotfixes may not update this key all the time.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My SQLServer has no "CurrentVersion" key, just a "Client" folder with "SNI10.0" and "SNI9.0" and "SuperSocketNetLib" directories in it. Presumably though one could check for the existance of these SNI9.0 (SQL Server 2005) and SNI10.0 (SQL Server 2008) directories. But enumerating the instances as in JohnW's post above works for me, so I'll likely go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, the above registry key works (and is available) for both SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

All the SQL Versions registry key will be under :
**`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`**

Based on different versios these are the registry keys for both 64 bit and 32 bit :

For SQL **2016** : `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft SQL Server 13`

For SQL **2014** : `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft SQL Server 12`

For SQL **2012** : `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft SQL Server 11`

For SQL **2008** : `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft SQL Server 10`

For SQL **2005**: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft SQL Server 2005`